# Forwarding X11 Displays to VNCs On RHEL8/RHEL9

Tags: rhel, x11, vnc, tigervnc

On previous versions of RHEL (RHEL5/6/7 at least) it was possible to create run a vncserver (from tigervnc-server) and forward X11 displays from another server by exporting the `DISPLAY` environment variable on the remote server to the `hostname:display` of the vncserver.

For example I have `workstation1`, `server1`, and `server2`. I could ssh from workstation1 to `server1`, start a vncserver on :1. Separately ssh to `server2` and run `export DISPLAY=server1:1`. Then run an X11 application on `server2`, and assuming proper xhost, firewall, and port listening settings it would appear in the vncserver on server1.

I've noticed on RHEL8 and RHEL9 that this is no longer the case. On RHEL7, when start a vncserver a listener comes up on two separate ports. One on 5900 + display number and one on 6000 + display number. On RHEL8 and RHEL9 the listener only comes up on 5900 + display.

Based on `strace` output from an attempt to forward `xeyes` to a vnc it appears that the connection to 6000 + display is still attempting to be made. In an attempt to "trick" the system I ran a vncserver on display 101, which created the listener on port 6001 on `server1`. Then ran `export DISPLAY=:1` on `server2` and attempted to run xeyes. It did try to connect to port `6001`, but was still denied.

`Error: Can't open display: server1:1`

Is there any way to enable the X11 listener when running vncserver on RHEL8 or RHEL9? I'm aware that using SSH forwarding still works, but I would like to be able to export the display and use native X11 forwarding over the network.

Also, in case it's relevant. I'm using plasma 5 as my DE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:
Add `listen=tcp` to a config file (e.g. /etc/tigervnc/vncserver-config-defaults)

I did some digging in the tigervnc git repo and found [this](https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/issues/1538). Specifically this:

> I recently learned that a valid entry would be "listen=tcp", which enables the server to listen on port 6000 for TCP connections

I added `listen=tcp` to `/etc/tigervnc/vncserver-config-defaults` and restarted my vncserver. I checked to see if it was listening on the 6000+display port and it was. Tried forwarding the X11 display again and everything worked.